# Puntuación negativa en una pregunta que no he respondido o modificado

Tags: soporte, reputación

Porque obtengo un **-2** en una pregunta que no he respondido, modificado y/o reportado

la pregunta en cuestión es la siguiente [¿Por qué no se muestra la imagen usando p:graphicImage?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3101/6635)

En mi historial de reputación me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si busco las palabras "*JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso*" me sale únicamente una pregunta, que es la que esta enlazada anteriormente

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es por una edición sugerida aprobada, y se revocaron los puntos debido a la eliminación.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10850